# How do I get access User's Google Calendar in my Ruby API when using it with React as a Frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

So, I am creating an app where I am using React as a Frontend and Rails as a Backend with Postgres database. I am using Google Oauth to authenticate users and also to get the access token so that I can make use of that access token to get User's Google Calendar Events. So, when the user Log's In to my app using Google Login, I will get the access token in React Frontend and then I will send it to the Ruby Backend API to store inside the user's table in access_token column. So, what should I do next if I want that user's Calendar Events?

I am not able to find any guide on this, so if anyone of you can help me with step by step procedure on what to do next then that will be great

Thank you!

Comment: This should help you out: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby

Comment: Don't worry too much about the token coming from react, so long as you have it in your rails application then you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `google_calender` gem.
Follow the configuration provided [here](https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar).

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing that great resource :)